# How to provide spring security with Amazon Cognito Identity Pools

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-security, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a spring boot application running in EC2 instance with AWS bean stack. how to provided spring security with AWS federated identities (Identity Pools).

These HTTP rest end point used in mobile and Web client. In my web http client i am able get temporary aws credentials using federated identities.

```
 AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){

        // Credentials will be available when this function is called.
        var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
        var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
        var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
        console.log(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey);
        console.log("sessionkey", sessionToken);

    });
```

how to authenticate AWS users using AWS sessionToken or Credentials in spring boot application.

Thanks.